Jenkins: the env vars MAVEN_OPTS and MAVEN_ARGS are ignored by Maven
On Jenkins, Maven ignores the environment variables MAVEN_OPTS and MAVEN_ARGS that I set in the same pipeline. Here the code I use:
pipeline {
    agent {    
        docker {            
            image 'iubar-maven-alpine'
            label 'docker'
            args '-v ${HOME}/.m2:/home/jenkins/.m2:rw,z'
        } 
    } 
    environment {
        MAVEN_ARGS = '--show-version --batch-mode'
        MAVEN_OPTS = '-Djava.awt.headless=true'     
    }   
    stages {    
        stage ('Build') {
            steps {         
                sh 'mvn clean compile'
            }
        }
...     

so to solve the problem I need to write :
...
        stage ('Build') {
            steps {         
                sh 'mvn $MAVEN_ARGS $MAVEN_OPTS clean compile'
            }
        }
...

What are the causes of this behavior ? And is there any better solutions ?

Your approach is valid. The issue arises because the Jenkins environment variables do not automatically get exposed to the shell you are running within the docker image. You could export the variables in your shell command or use the withEnv block but both of them are more verbose than your solution. One cleaner variant you could try is to move the env variables to your docker arguments with the -e flag like so  args '-v ${HOME}/.m2:/home/jenkins/.m2:rw,z -e MAVEN_ARGS="--show-version --batch-mode" -e MAVEN_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true"'

@Hangrybear666 except they are, which is the exact reason the environment { ... } syntax exists in Jenkins Pipelines. Jenkins explicitly passes all of the environment variables defined there (plus adds it's own ones) to the container run command - the -e ... flags should be visible in the build log). I would rather suspect that the OP uses a Maven version older than 3.9.0 because it's the first Maven version that supports the MAVEN_ARGS environment variable.

@AlexanderPletnev you're right the problem is I was using the 3.8.5 version of maven. Thank you for your reply. Please, even reply with an answer to get my vote. Bye.


What are the causes of this behavior?

Maven supports the MAVEN_ARGS environment variable only starting with version 3.9.0. By the way, it also allows to specify the goals, not only the flags.
The reason why it worked for you when you ran the command like sh 'mvn $MAVEN_ARGS $MAVEN_OPTS clean compile is because you placed an environment variable after mvn - so your shell interpolated them into the command just as arguments. If you put the environment variables before the mvn call, the expected result would be the same as when you defined them in the environment block of your Jenkinsfile.

And is there any better solutions?

Just update your Maven version. Your original approach is the canonical one. I confirmed this behavior with Maven 3.8.8 and 3.9.6.
Also, remember that Maven can take the configuration not only from the environment variables you used, but from settings.xml and the configuration files located in .mvn directory.

I was using the 3.8.5 version of maven. Thank you
